# Is this how to calculate annualized return?

Tags: rate-of-return

For a savings account that is returning 2.0 APR, on $10,000, $200 in interest will be earned in one year.

If I have a return of 9% on a stock trade with a holding period of 3 months, is the annualized return 4 x 9% = 36%?

Doesn't that assume I will make 9% on three additional trades? What if those three trades are all negative? Now the annualized return isn't even 9% anymore.

If the above is incorrect, what is considered the annualized return on the stock trade?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Doesn't that assume I will make 9% on three additional trades?

No (well, sort of, but not really). "annualized" doesn't mean "what will my return be in one year". It means "what's the *equivalent* annual return of this non-annual investment". So yes, to *get* 36% over one year you're *assuming* that the return is replicable (meaning that IF you earned 9% each quarter, then your return over one year would be 36%), but you're not really *assuming* that it WILL return that over the next 9 months.

Also, to be technical, if you earned 9% *each quarter* and the returns compounded (meaning you earn 9% *on top of* the 9% you earned last quarter), then your annualized return would be

```
(1.09 * 1.09 * 1.09 * 1.09) = 1.41 = 41% annual return
```

So the *compounding period* can make a difference in the calculation as well.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? It seems contradictory: "you're assuming that the return is replicable, but you're not really assuming that it WILL return that over the next 9 months."

Comment: I added a bit, what I meant was that IF the investment earned another 9% each quarter, not that you are assuming that it WILL (meaning you cannot EXPECT it to replicate the return from the first quarter). In other words, the _calculation_ assumes that it will, but just to make the result equivalent, not to imply that past results imply future results.

Comment: Right - that's my point: Depending on what happens with returns over the next 3 quarters, it could be anywhere from negative to higher than 36%. That's meaningless. To much assumption going on. Reproducing 9% four times in a row is quite a feat. Guess I still don't understand.

Comment: Think about it this way - it's correct to say "my annualized return over the last three months is 36%". It's wrong to say "in one year I WILL have a 36% return". Yes your return _might_ be different over an entire year, but in order to compare the return to investments over different time periods, annualization puts everything in the same context.

Comment: Or another way - how would you compare one stock that earned 9% over the last three months versus one that earned 30% over the last year? which one has the higher return? How would you quantify that?

Comment: I see what you are saying. It simply assumes way too much. For the 9% vs. 30% comparison, I'd say 9% is what that stock earned over a year if it was only the one trade within a year. Nothing wrong with that. Unless there were more trades on the same stock within the year. Then it's a matter of adding the returns to get a real number. Otherwise, it's pie in the sky.

Comment: As D Stanley mentioned, the purpose of annualizing an investment return is to compare investments of differing time periods.  It's a meaningless assumption that one can achieve that annualized return because each subsequent trade will have a different return and possibly a different duration.

Comment: @4thSpace Yes if you did _nothing_ else then your _actual_ annual return would be 9%. But if you compared the two trades the 9% one had a better return _over an equivalent time period_. That's the point.

Comment: @4thSpace: Think of it this way:  suppose that right now you are traveling at 100 kilometers per hour.  This does not necessarily mean that you will be 100 km away one hour from now;  it merely means that *if* you continued at the same rate, you *would* be 100 km away.  Just because it's a hypothetical situation about the future doesn't mean that "100 km/h" isn't a useful number about how fast you're going.  Similarly, just because your rate of return won't necessarily hold up over an entire year doesn't mean that the annualized rate is a meaningless number.

Comment: @4thSpace you don't necessarily have to trade the *same* stock again, you're free to put the money in any other place once you sell the stock in 3 months. If you are then equally lucky/skilled to put money in other stocks yielding 9% in 3 months, you have the chance of 41% returns. On the other hand you cannot invest in anything else if your money is locked in a savings account for 1 year. That's why it's useful to compare annualised returns.